# Any problems with having Code::Blocks and MS Visual Studio on same machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, codeblocks

I have installed Code::Blocks on my (Windows) machine. It is working fine.

However there are some open source libraries that i would like to use. For this i will have to build the library on my machine. However the source code is available in the form of a MS Visual Studio solution file.

I've tried to use the 'Import Project' feature of Code::Blocks but got errors with that. I am now thinking of installing MS Visual Studio express edition to see if can build the library using it. I do want to keep my install of Code::Blocks.

I wanted to ask if there are any problems having these two IDEs (Code::Blocks & MS Visual Studio Express Edition) on the same machine? I know they use different default compilers.

Comment: no, there won't be any problem.

Comment: I really wonder if Stack Overflow is the right place to ask questions like these though.

Comment: Thank you for your input Raphael. What would be a good forum to ask a question like this?